# Solve a differential equation that leads to elliptic solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From the symmetry of a PDE, I have the following ODE I wish to solve.

$$
\frac{1}{2}v^2_y = -\frac{1}{6}v^3 - \frac{1}{2}cv^2 + kv + l
$$

The text I am looking at (Olver) states the general solution can be written in terms of an elliptic function.

I want to understand how this is found.

Comment: This comes about when you solve for $v_y$ and use separation of variables, resulting in $dv = \pm \sqrt{2\ell + 2kv - cv^2 - \frac{1}{3}v^3}dy$. Integrating gives $F(v) = y + C$ where $F$ is an elliptic integral. Its inverse is called an elliptic function.

Comment: I understand the isolating $v_y$ and the separation of variables. However I don't understand how to apply the concept of elliptic integral. How do I recognise a function as an elliptical function?